# Installation of openzeppelin/contracts Library

Tags: ethereum, truffle, openzeppelin

I have created a node.js project, within which I have created a truffle directory and initialised its project. I have installed the openzeppelin (npm install @openzeppelin/contracts) library in this truffle project directory, but nothing appears to have been installed, although I did not received any error during the install process. The import statement in my project displays the error hereafter:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
```

> Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they changed the name, and now the contract name is

`ERC721.sol` and not `ERC721Full.sol`, so try

`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import "github.com/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol"
```